# How to array from model to use it with jquery in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to loop through model collection in razor and then use that collection in jquery in client side

I need something like that   var MyArray = @item.TagName and after that i need to use MyArray with jquery in client side
Here is my code

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Tags)
  {

          @item.TagName

   }
```

Thank you

Comment: `var tags = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tags))'; var firstTagName = tags[0].TagName;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small example using `Json.Encode`:

```
@{
    var list = new List<TagItem>() {
        new TagItem() { TagName = "1" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "2" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "3" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "4" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "5" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "6" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "7" },
        new TagItem() { TagName = "8" }
    };

    var onlynames = list.Select(x => x.TagName);
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(list));
        var json1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(onlynames));
    </script>
}
```

Variable `json` will be an array of `TagItems` and `json1` will be an array of names.

Value of `json`

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

which every object will contain the property `TagName` inside it.

`json1` will be directly a string.

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much for your help and effort

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score -1):

That code that you have executes on the server. Its purpose is to render HTML markup that will **later** be processed by the browser. Since HTML can contain JS code, you have the opportunity to render a `SCRIPT` tag that contains data that you want.

For example:

```
<script>

    var arr = [];

         @foreach (var item in Model.Tags)
          {

                 arr.push("@item.TagName");

           }
</script>
```

This should be placed before/above the code that would be using that `arr` variable. I only guessed the syntax related to quotes in `arr.push("@item.TagName");`; it might needs some tweaks, but as a result, you want to see something like this in the page-source within the browser:

```
<script>    
    var arr = [];    
    arr.push("tag1");
    arr.push("tag2");
</script>
```

EDIT: Maybe try this within that `@foreach`:

```
"arr.push(\"" + @item.TagName + "\";"
```

Comment: You're implying that that solution above is hard, which it isn't. No, I can't think of any other simpler solution that accommodates your setup. Of course, you could expose the same data through a dedicated HTTP endpoint, but that's even more complex (while it may be a better fit; who knows). I think you should just try the above; you'll be surprised.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer for the question that @twernt pointed to - the syntax for the "push" statement might be more accurate/correct then what I suggested. I haven't worked with razor that much to be certain, and I'm lazy to set that up. That's an exercise for you :)

Comment: Or, take a look at how to **serialize** an array (or an object, in general) to JSON. You need to serialize `this.Model.Tags.Select(t=>t.TagName).ToArray()` to JSON array to get this in page-source (sample): `var arr = [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]`. Still wrap with SCRIPT tags, of course.